# Draw a pixel to the screen in x86-64 assembly

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, x86-64, masm

I've been trying to draw even 1 pixel to the screen in x86-64 assembly with masm visual studio

I've found online that you can use `int 10h` to make the screen into 320x200 256 color mode but when i try to use this i get an error

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF6F2341014 in assemblyproject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

and i cant make this go away

I've also found that `0xA0000h` is the location in memory to draw to the screen but when i try to write there i get another error

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF7A4AF101F in assemblyproject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000000A0000.
```

i have tried for multiple days to make this work but i have not even gotten 1 pixel onto the screen and i don't know what more i can do or how to fix anything

I'm using windows 10 operating system

Comment: You can use BIOS interfaces (`int 10h`) under Windows. You'll have to use the same Windows API calls that you would use in a C or C++ program.

Comment: @RossRidge You surely mean “You cannot use BIOS interfaces...”

Comment: Sorry, yes. I meant that you cannot use BIOS interfaces under Windows.

Comment: can you call the windows API calls directly from assembly or do you have to do it from c, because my program has no c only assembly

Comment: @NathanielSmith - no different from asm, c,c++ or another language you call api